# Problema con asignacion de variable char en c++

Tags: c++, string, texto

Quisiera crear dos variables char, una que sea igual a: "Hola mundo!" y otra que tenga el valor de la primera variable, pero partiendo desde el caracter 5, dando como resultado que esta variable tenga el valor de "Mundo!".

Intente `char variable2 = variablechar1[5]` pero solo me da el caracter 5 y no lo demas del texto

Comment: Usa la función `substr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo primero es que el tipo de datos `char` es para almacenar caracteres, por lo que si quieres almacenar una palabra tendrías que crear un arreglo de tipo `char` o declararla de tipo `string`, que para mí en tu caso sería lo mejor usar variables de tipo `string` y le asignas la función `substr` a la segunda variable pasándole como parámetro la variable1 en la posición del caracter  deseada

Comment: Me funciono!, muchas gracias william!

Comment: Por si no queda claro, el tipo `char` es para almacenar un solo caracter. Lógicamente necesitas un arreglo de caracteres para almacenar una palabra o cualquier texto que ocupe más de un caracter.

Comment: Puedes mejorar tu respuesta con enlaces a [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que los arrays o vectores, se deben de manejar de manera diferente a las variables normales, pues su estructura es diferente.

En esencia, un array es un tipo de dato cuya principal función es almacenar otros datos, por ende, utilizar `=` para asignar valores solo será posible de dos maneras:

La primera forma es en la definición del array. Por ejemplo:

```
char variablechar1[10] = "hola mundo"; // cada letra toma una posición de 0 a 9 dentro del array.
```

La otra manera sería asignando elementos de uno en uno, para lo cual se debe de indicar la posición donde se asigna tal elemento. Ejemplo:

```
variablechar1[3] = 'i'; // asigna el elemento 'i' en la posición 3 del array.
```

Es preciso recordar entonces  que en C++, fuera de la definición de una variable tipo array, en la expresión `array[valor]` la variable `valor` indica una posición y no una cantidad. Además, la diferencia entre un array y una variable unidimensional es la notación de la dimensión entre corchetes:

```
char variablechar2 = variablechar1[5]; // le asignas el elemento en la posición '5' a una variable unidimensional de tipo char. 

char variablechar; //unidimensional
char variablechar[5]; // array de tamaño 5
```

En tu caso sería mejor utilizar una variable tipo `string` (cadena) y la función `substr` para obtener lo que necesitas.